# Remove swipe effect in gallery from top to bottom in android

Tags: android

I have developed a custom gallery and override the on-fling method in it to swipe one image at a time.It worked, but the problem is when i swipe from top to bottom or vice-versa the image gets swiped and hence changes.

Below is my code

```
public class mygallery extends Gallery {

public mygallery(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(ctx, attrSet);

}

private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2) {
    return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
}

private boolean isScrollingRight(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){
    return e2.getX() < e1.getX();

}



@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    int kEvent=0;
    if (isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)) { // Check if scrolling left
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
    } else if(isScrollingRight(e1, e2)) { // Otherwise scrolling right
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
    } 
    onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
    return true;
}
```

}

How can i get rid of swiping of images(top to bottom,bottom to top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY))
    {
        // This is an horizontal fling
        // Do your operation here
    }     
    else
        // This is an vertical fling
 }
```