# Android Gallary Example

Tags: android, image-gallery

I have just done some code for Gallary and now its working fine.I have followed this Link for that http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html. But my concept is still not clear.I have used there stylable, what is this?And one more thing, Is it possible to change gallary displaying mode(I mean its default mode is L-R or R-L can we change it Top-Bottom or Bottom-Top).

```
TypedArray attr = mContext
                .obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay, you can't change the default behavior of the Gallery in Android.

If still you wants to make gallery works top and bottom moving you need to customized the gallery specifically for your application.

Comment: Thanks @Arun for this advice but i'm not getting how can be changed.So can you Provide me some example or any Link ?

Comment: Have a look at that link, This might help u ...      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280909/remove-swipe-effect-in-gallery-from-top-to-bottom-in-android